# Is there any way to get support of IE 8 with JSX and ES6 to React JS

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs

New to React.js and R & D on google found React 0.14.X version supports IE 8 browser. but Babel's(JSX Transformer) Browser.js doesn't not working on IE8 browser. there is a no error in console regarding in IE 8 browser. Please suggest the whole architecture of React js with JSX which supports IE 8 too.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-app"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>


    <script>
     var contacts = [
              {key: 1, name: "Anurag Dadheech", email: "anurag.dadheech@gmal.com", description: "This is descrption"},
              {key: 2, name: "Priyank Soni", email: "priyank.soni@gmai.com"},
              {key: 3, name: "Jayesh Helaiya", email: "jayesh@gmal.com"},
            ]

            var ContactItem = React.createClass({
              propTypes: {
                name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                email: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                description: React.PropTypes.string,
              },

              render: function() {
                // I wrap mult-line return statements in parentheses to avoid the
                // inevitable bugs caused by forgetting that JavaScript will throw away
                // the final lines when possible. The parentheses are not strictly
                // necessary.
                return (
                  React.createElement('li', {},
                    React.createElement('h2', {}, this.props.name),
                    React.createElement('a', {href: 'mailto:'+this.props.email}, this.props.email),
                    React.createElement('div', {}, this.props.description)
                  )
                )
              },
            })

            var contactItemElements = contacts
              .filter(function(contact) { return contact.email })
              .map(function(contact) { return React.createElement(ContactItem, contact) })

            var rootElement =
              React.createElement('div', {}, 
                React.createElement('h1', {}, "Contacts"),
                React.createElement('ul', {}, contactItemElements)
              )

            ReactDOM.render(rootElement, document.getElementById('react-app'))
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works fine in chrome and Firefox but in IE 8 it gives

```
__SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' is null or not and object
```

Comment: Could you please show us the exact error you are getting? Also what are you using, webapck, browserify, Grunt? Can we see your config files? Thanks

Comment: Actually we have not started the working on project but verifying all aspects work on IE 8 so i have created a demo app.

Comment: @Stelios Voskos i have posted the code and error please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React js community says they provide IE8 support for 0.14.x but most of utilities are not working in IE8 so it is good if you go for angularjs 1.2.x. there is a lot of support regarding IE8. you will never regret.